# Split por ponto com exceções

Tags: javascript, regex

Tenho a seguinte regex:

```
(?! ).*?[|.!?:;\b\t\n](?![|.!?:;\b\t\n]|(\.\d))(?<!\bDr\.|\bINC\.|\binc\.|\bInc\.|\bNO\.|\bNo\.|\bno\.|\bN\.|\bn\.|\bReg\|\breg\.|\bREG\.|\bCo\.|\bDra\.|\bSrs\.|\bSr\.|\bSra\.|\bSra\.|\bFl\.|S\.|A\.|\bSras\.|\&|\&amp;\d\.)
```

Na frase: "Tenho 190.000 pontos, meu e-mail é lorem.ipsum@dolor.com.br. Muito obrigado."

Ele vira uma array da seguinte forma:

```
Tenho 190.
000 pontos, meu e-mail é lorem.
ispum@dolor.
com.
br.
Muito obrigado.
```

Quando na verdade preciso escapar o ponto entre 2 letras e números.

O que espero é:

```
Tenho 190.000 pontos, meu e-mail é lorem.ipsum@dolor.com.br.
Muito Obrigado.
```

Comment: Não entendi bem não. Me parece que vc quer apenas separar o "Muito obrigado" do resto da frase. Ou então não ficou bem explicado a questão. Usar regex baseado em padrões, qual é o padrão? Isso que não entendi bem.

Comment: A frase foi apenas um exemplo, preciso explodir uma string em "." mas preciso escapar quando esse ponto estiver entre 2 numeros/letras

Comment: Sei, mas antes do "Muito obrigado" existe um espaço, o que não é uma letra nem número.

Comment: Por isso ele deve ser explodido ali.

Comment: Não é mais fácil ver a regra como sendo qualquer ponto seguido de espaço? Uma regex simples como esta: `\.\s` resolve o problema.

Comment: Precisa continuar seguindo a regra da regex, quebrando também por |.!?:;\b\t\n e com suas devidas exceções Dr., Dra., INC. e etc..

Comment: @MaxFratane O `\s` também corresponde `newline character`, portanto creio que somente o espaço seria melhor `\.( )` e fazendo um replace do espaço no subgroup por uma nova linha `\n`

Answer (score 1):

Você até poderia usar algo como `split(/\.\s/)` (separar por um ponto seguido de espaço), mas o problema é que o `split` removerá o ponto da primeira string (e pelo jeito você quer mantê-lo).

Então o jeito é usar um [*lookbehind*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```js
let frase = "Tenho 190.000 pontos, meu e-mail é lorem.ipsum@dolor.com.br. Muito obrigado.";
console.log(frase.split(/(?<=\.)\s/));
// [ "Tenho 190.000 pontos, meu e-mail é lorem.ipsum@dolor.com.br.", "Muito obrigado." ]
```

Uma característica do *lookbehind* é que ele verifica se algo existe antes  de determinada posição da string, mas o trecho verificado não faz parte do *match*, e por isso ele não é removido no `split`.

No caso acima, o *lookbehind* é `(?<=\.)` - ou seja, ele verifica se existe um ponto (`\.`) antes da posição atual. E a posição atual, no caso, é `\s` (que corresponde a vários caracteres, como o espaço, <kbd>TAB</kbd> ou quebras de linha - [veja a lista completa na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes#Types)).

Isso garante que a quebra será feita nos espaços, mas só aqueles que possuem um ponto antes. Como o ponto está em um *lookbehind*, ele não faz parte do *match* e por isso não é removido pelo `split` - já o espaço é removido, por isso o resultado é o array:

```
[ "Tenho 190.000 pontos, meu e-mail é lorem.ipsum@dolor.com.br.", "Muito obrigado." ]
```

Você também poderia usar a regex `/(?<=\.)[^a-z\d]/i`: no caso, em vez de `\s`, estou usando `[^a-z\d]` (tudo que **não** for uma letra de `a` a `z` ou um dígito (`\d`), e a [*flag* `i`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters) indica que a regex será *case insensitive* (ou seja, tanto faz se forem letras maiúsculas ou minúsculas). Dependendo dos seus casos de uso, pode fazer mais sentido usar essa opção (que vai pegar qualquer coisa que não seja letra ou número, o que inclui sinais de pontuação, hífen, etc) ou `\s` (que pega somente os espaços e quebras de linha). Escolha o que se adequar melhor aos seus casos de uso.

---

#### Mas ainda não acabou

Apesar de não ter um exemplo, você cita que há exceções, como "Dr.", "INC." e outros, que não devem fazer parte do `split`.

Nesse caso, a regex fica um pouco mais complicada. Por exemplo, para considerar "Dr.", "Dra." e "INC." como exceções:

```js
let frase = "Tenho 190.000 pontos, meu e-mail é lorem.ipsum@dolor.com.br. Muito obrigado, Dr. Fulano.";
let partes = frase.split(/(?<=(?<!dra?|inc)\.)\s/i);

console.log(partes);
// [ "Tenho 190.000 pontos, meu e-mail é lorem.ipsum@dolor.com.br.", "Muito obrigado, Dr. Fulano." ]
```

Agora eu também uso um *negative lookbehind* (o trecho `(?<! ... )`), que verifica se algo **não** existe antes de determinada posição. No caso, a expressão é `dra?|inc`: a string "dr", seguida por um "a" opcional (`a?` quer dizer que o `a` é [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)), **ou** (o "ou" é indicado pelo `|`) a string "inc". A flag `i` garante que pode ser tanto "DR." quanto "dr.", ou "Dr.", etc.

Isso quer dizer que o `split` é feito nos espaços (`\s`), desde que eles tenham um ponto antes, mas esse ponto não pode ter antes dele uma das strings citadas ("Dr", "Dra", "Inc").

Para colocar todas as suas condições, ficaria assim:

```
frase.split(/(?<=(?<!dra?|sra?s?|inc|reg|co|bn)\.)\s/i)
```

Agora tenho várias opções (todas separadas por `|`):

- `dra?`: as letras "dr" seguidas de um "a" opcional, que serve tanto para "dr" quanto para "dra"
- `sra?s?`: as letras "sr" seguidas de um "a" opcional, seguidas de um "s" opcional, assim ele serve para "sr", "srs", "sra" e "sras"
- as demais opções ("inc", "reg", etc)

Se quiser adicionar mais expressões, basta ir colocando na regex (sempre separando por `|`).

---

#### Compatibilidade e alternativas

Infelizmente o *negative lookahead* [não é um recurso que está disponível em todos os browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-RegExp_Lookbehind_Assertions). Mas se quiser, [é possível simulá-lo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/361801/112052) (com muita "ginástica").

---

Outra alternativa (que também usa *negative lookbehind*) é fazer um `match` ao invés de um `split`, afinal de contas, [*match* e *split* são dois lados da mesma moeda](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#splitvsmatch). No `split` você diz o que não quer que esteja no resultado final, já no `match` você diz o que quer:

```js
let frase = "Tenho 190.000 pontos, meu e-mail é lorem.ipsum@dolor.com.br. Muito obrigado, Dr. Fulano de Tal.";
let regex = /.+?(?<=(?<!dra?|sra?s?|inc|reg|co|bn)\.)(?:\s|$)/ig;

while ((matches = regex.exec(frase)) !== null) {
    console.log(matches[0].trim());
}
```

A regex é parecida, mas agora colocamos `.+?` (um ou mais caracteres). Ou seja, eu quero pegar vários caracteres, até encontrar um espaço (`\s`), desde que esse espaço tenha um ponto antes (mas desde que esse ponto não tenha antes "Dr", "Dra", etc). O detalhe é que o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` é ganancioso e tenta pegar o máximo de caracteres que puder (o que faria ele ir até o final da string, por exemplo). Para cancelar este comportamento e parar no primeiro espaço que satisfaça a condição, eu coloco o `?` logo depois.

Eu também uso a *flag* `g`, que permite percorrer a string procurando todos os *matches*, e para cada *match* eu uso o método `trim()`, já que o *match* também contém o espaço no final. O resultado é:

```
Tenho 190.000 pontos, meu e-mail é lorem.ipsum@dolor.com.br. 
Muito obrigado, Dr. Fulano de Tal.
```

Se quiser guardar os resultados em um array:

```js
let frase = "Tenho 190.000 pontos, meu e-mail é lorem.ipsum@dolor.com.br. Muito obrigado, Dr. Fulano de Tal.";
let regex = /.+?(?<=(?<!dra?|sra?s?|inc|reg|co|bn)\.)(?:\s|$)/ig;
let resultados = [];

while ((matches = regex.exec(frase)) !== null) {
    resultados.push(matches[0].trim());
}

console.log(resultados);
```