# Negative lookbehind só funciona no Google Chrome, existe uma alternativa para os outros browsers?

Tags: javascript, regex

O regex `/(?<!,),(?!,)/` apresenta instabilidade em algumas versões de browsers.

Encontrei esse regex no sistema da empresa que trabalho, e não entendi muito bem o objetivo dele. Aparentemente o problema está no `<`, no Edge não funciona, nem no Mozilla. Qual o problema com a expressão?

Teste no [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/KUb6pT/5).

Código que estava no prototype da `String`:

```
String.prototype.scapeSplit = function (v) {
        var r_split = new RegExp('(?<!' + v + ')' + v + '(?!' + v + ')');
        var r_replace = new RegExp(v + '{2}');

        var s = this.split(r_split);
        return s.map(function (x) {
            return x.replace(r_replace, v);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hiago, a minha resposta original só funcionava quando o `v` tem apenas um caractere. Editei a resposta e adicionei uma solução mais geral, que funciona com strings de qualquer tamanho

Comment: Suporta a partir da versão 78 do Mozilla Firefox, que foi lançada em junho de 2020. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Como já disseram nas outras respostas, o problema é o trecho `(?<!,)`, que é um [*negative lookbehind*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind). No caso, ele verifica se **não** existe uma vírgula antes do caractere desejado (que no caso, também é uma vírgula). Se tiver, a regex falha.

E logo em seguida temos `(?!,)`, que é um *negative lookahead*, que verifica se não há uma vírgula depois. Portanto `/(?<!,),(?!,)/` serve para capturar as vírgulas que não possuem uma outra vírgula antes ou depois, o que é outro modo de dizer que a regex não pega os casos em que há duas ou mais vírgulas seguidas ([exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/NO1jW3/3)).

Como você está usando esta regex em um [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), significa que a string será separada somente nas posições em que há uma vírgula (desde que não tenha uma vírgula antes ou depois). Ou seja, se tiver duas ou mais vírgulas seguidas, elas não são consideradas no `split`.

**Obs: na época em que a pergunta foi feita**, esta sintaxe não estava disponível em todos os *browsers*, como o Firefox (citado na pergunta). Mas vendo [este link](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-RegExp_Lookbehind_Assertions) hoje - julho/2021 - podemos constatar que vários outros browsers, como Firefox e Edge, agora têm suporte (mas de qualquer forma, ainda não é algo implementado em todos, por isso a alternativa mais abaixo continua sendo uma opção).

Rodei o seu código no Chrome (código abaixo):

```js
String.prototype.scapeSplit = function (v) {
  let r_split = new RegExp('(?<!' + v + ')' + v + '(?!' + v + ')');
  let r_replace = new RegExp(v + '{2}');

  let s = this.split(r_split);
  // split produz a lista ["ab", "cd,,ef", "gh,,,ij", "kl"]
  return s.map(function (x) {
      return x.replace(r_replace, v);
  });
}

let s = 'ab,cd,,ef,gh,,,ij,kl';

// ["ab", "cd,ef", "gh,,ij", "kl"]
console.log(s.scapeSplit(','));
```

Como o Chrome já suporta *lookbehinds*, o código rodou sem problemas. Vi que seu código primeiro faz o `split`. Usando a string `'ab,cd,,ef,gh,,,ij,kl'` e fazendo o `split` com vírgula, a primeira regex quebra a string somente onde não há duas ou mais vírgulas seguidas.

Então o resultado é a lista `["ab", "cd,,ef", "gh,,,ij", "kl"]`. Em seguida é feito um `map` nesta lista, substituindo duas vírgulas seguidas (`v + '{2}'`, que resulta em `,{2}`- duas vírgulas seguidas) por apenas uma. Ou seja, `cd,,ef` é transformado em `cd,ef` e `gh,,,ij`, em `gh,,ij`.

O resultado final é a lista `["ab", "cd,ef", "gh,,ij", "kl"]`.

---

### Alternativa para os browsers que não suportam *lookbehind*

Como este recurso não é suportado em todos os browsers, a abordagem deve ser um pouco diferente. Em vez de `split`, vou usar o método [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), e na regex usarei a [*flag* `g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters), que faz com que seja retornado um array com todos os *matches* encontrados.

Mas usarei uma regex diferente, já que a lógica será inversa. Enquanto no `split` eu coloco uma regex com as coisas que eu **não** quero no resultado final (vírgula que não tem outra vírgula antes ou depois), no `match` eu faço o oposto: coloco as coisas que eu quero que estejam no resultado final (no fundo, `split` e `match` [são apenas dois lados da mesma moeda](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#splitvsmatch)). Enfim, o que eu quero que esteja no resultado final é:

- uma sequência de caracteres que não sejam vírgula
- **opcionalmente** seguidos por uma sequência de duas ou mais vírgulas
- esta sequência toda pode se repetir várias vezes (por exemplo, se tiver um trecho `aa,,bb,,,cc,,,dd`, tudo isso é um único elemento que o `split` não separou, então o `match` deve ter uma regex que considera tudo isso uma coisa só).

No caso, vou usar `([^,]+(,{2,})?)+`. Explicando de dentro para fora:

- `[^,]+`: O delimitador `[^` representa uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), ou seja, a regex considera qualquer caractere que não seja o que está entre `[^` e `]`. No caso, só tem a vírgula. E o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências". Ou seja, é uma sequência de vários caracteres que não sejam vírgula.
- `(,{2,})?`: o trecho `,{2,}` significa "duas ou mais vírgulas", e o `?` torna todo este trecho opcional. Isso quer dizer que pode ter uma sequência de várias vírgulas, ou não.
- O `+` em torno de toda a expressão (agrupada entre parênteses) diz que isso pode se repetir várias vezes. Ou seja, todo o conjunto "vários caracteres que não são vírgula, seguidos ou não de várias vírgulas" pode se repetir várias vezes.

Isso garante que trechos como `ab`, `ab,,cd` e `ab,,cd,,,ef` serão considerados uma coisa só. Exemplo:

```js
let matches = 'ab,cd,,ef,gh,,,ij,kl'.match(/([^,]+(,{2,})?)+/g);
console.log(matches); // ["ab", "cd,,ef", "gh,,,ij", "kl"]
```

O resultado foi o array `["ab", "cd,,ef", "gh,,,ij", "kl"]`, exatamente o mesmo que seu código original obtém antes do `map`. Ou seja, agora basta fazer o `map` e seu código está pronto:

```js
String.prototype.scapeSplit = function (v) {
  let r_match = new RegExp('([^' + v  + ']+(' + v + '{2,})?)+', 'g');
  let r_replace = new RegExp(v + '{2}');

  let s = this.match(r_match);
  // match produz a lista ["ab", "cd,,ef", "gh,,,ij", "kl"]
  return s.map(function (x) {
      return x.replace(r_replace, v);
  });
}

let s = 'ab,cd,,ef,gh,,,ij,kl';

// ["ab", "cd,ef", "gh,,ij", "kl"]
console.log(s.scapeSplit(','));
```

O resultado será o array `["ab", "cd,ef", "gh,,ij", "kl"]`.

---

## Expressões com mais de um caractere

A solução acima funciona bem quando o parâmetro passado para `scapeSplit` possui apenas um caractere.

Caso o parâmetro tenha mais de um caractere, há algumas modificações a serem feitas.

Se o browser suportar *negative lookbehind* (como é o caso do Chrome), basta corrigir a regex que faz o `replace` para:

```
let r_replace = new RegExp('(' + v + '){2}');
```

Caso `v` seja, por exemplo, a string `12`: se não tiver parênteses, o resultado é `12{2}` (o número `1`, seguido de dois números `2`). Mas eu quero na verdade `(12){2}` (duas ocorrências de `12`). Corrigindo isso, você pode usar a string `'12'` no `split` que funcionará sem problemas, seguindo a mesma lógica da vírgula (só separar por `12` se não tiver outra ocorrência de `12` antes ou depois).

---

Caso o browser não suporte *negative lookbehind*, não podemos usar `[^...]` como foi feito acima, então a solução é um pouco mais complicada¹:

```js
String.prototype.scapeSplit = function (v) {
  let r_match = new RegExp('(?:' + v + ')(?!(' + v + ')+)', 'g');
  let lookbehind = new RegExp(v + '$'); // simula o lookbehind
  let indices = [], match;
  // primeiro obtém os índices em que a expressão ocorre
  while (match = r_match.exec(this)) {
      if (match.index == r_match.lastIndex) r_match.lastIndex++;
      // obtém a substring de zero até o índice em que o match ocorre
      let leftContext = match.input.substring(0, match.index);
      if (! lookbehind.exec(leftContext)) { // simular lookbehind negativo
          indices.push({ start: match.index, end: match.index + match[0].length });
      }
  }
  // agora faz o split pelas posições encontradas acima
  let pos = 0;
  let result = [];
  indices.forEach(i => {
      result.push(this.substring(pos, i.start));
      pos = i.end;
  });
  // não esquecer do último
  result.push(this.substring(pos));

  let r_replace = new RegExp('(' + v + '){2}');
  // o indices.forEach acima produz a lista result = ["ab", "cd1212ef", "gh121212ij", "kl"]
  return result.map(function (x) {
      return x.replace(r_replace, v);
  });
}

let s = 'ab12cd1212ef12gh121212ij12kl';

// ["ab", "cd12ef", "gh1212ij", "kl"]
console.log(s.scapeSplit('12'));
```

Se o parâmetro for, por exemplo, a string `'12'`, a primeira regex (`r_match`) fica `(?:12)(?!(12)+)`. Ou seja, a string `12`, desde que não esteja seguida de uma ou mais ocorrências de `12`.

Em seguida eu faço um `while` percorrendo todos os *matches* desta regex na string. A cada vez que encontro um, eu uso **outra** regex para simular o *lookbehind*. Eu faço isso obtendo uma substring que corresponde à string original, do início até o ponto em que o *match* foi encontrado (`match.index`). Se este trecho termina com a string indicada, quer dizer que o *lookbehind* encontrou uma repetição da string (mas como eu quero um *negative lookbehind*, eu faço `if (!lookbehind.exec(leftContext))`).

Por exemplo, se a string de entrada começar com `ab12cd`, o *match* é encontrado na posição 2 (onde começa o `12`). Então eu faço um `substring` até a posição 2 (resultando em `ab`) e verifico se essa string termina em `12` (ou seja, estou simulando o que o lookbehind faria).

Então eu guardo o `match.index` (posição em que o *match* ocorreu) e `match.index + match[0].length` (posição em que ele termina = posição inicial do *match* mais o tamanho da string encontrada). Ao final deste `while`, eu tenho todas as posições em que os *matches* ocorreram. Com isso eu sei exatamente onde tenho que fazer o `split`.

Em seguida eu faço um `forEach` por esses índices, usando `substring` para pegar o trecho indicado e adiciono estas substrings em um array. No fim das contas eu apenas simulei o que o `split` faria caso o *lookbehind* fosse suportado.

Por fim, faço o `replace` para eliminar as repetições, tal como foi feito com a vírgula (lembrando de colocar os parênteses).

PS: o trecho `if (match.index == r_match.lastIndex) r_match.lastIndex++;` é feito para corrigir um bug para os casos de *zero width matches* ([explicado neste link](http://www.regexguru.com/2008/04/watch-out-for-zero-length-matches/)). Ele não ocorre para as strings e regex específicas que estamos usando, mas em todo caso fica o registro.

---

<sup>(1) - Esta solução que simula o *lookbehind* foi baseada [neste livro](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/).</sup>

Comment: Perfeito @hkotsubo me ajudou muito!! Obrigado.

Answer (score 7):

```
/(?<!,),(?!,)/
```

1. `(?!)` - negative lookahead
2. `(?<!)` - negative lookbehind

O que falha no seu código é essa parte: `(?<!)`, **Lookbehinds** só estão disponíveis em navegadores que suportam o padrão `ECMA2018`, e isso significa que apenas as versões mais recentes do `Chrome` podem lidar com elas. Mais: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/

Seu regex é o seguinte:

Encontre `,` onde `,` não precede e `,` não segue, ou seja, encontre virgulas onde não tenha virgulas nem antes e depois. Veja que no seu regex101 onde tem `,,,` não é retornado porque há virgulas antes e depois!

Uma alternativa é trocar o `lookbehind` por um código que seja compatível com outros navegadores

Fontes que usei como referência:

1. [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)
2. [Javascript regex negative lookbehind not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011366/javascript-regex-negative-lookbehind-not-working-in-firefox)
3. [Retirar uma parte da URL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/353199/retirar-uma-parte-da-url/353202#353202)

Comment: Obrigado Marconi, como eu faria isso no ECMA2015?

Comment: Só um minuto @HiagoSouza estou bolando uma maneira!

Comment: Muito obrigado @Marconi.

Comment: @HiagoSouza talvez a resposta do hkotsubo possa te ajudar!

Comment: Sua resposta foi de grande ajuda, porém a resposta abaixo está mais completa e é injusto eu marcar a sua como correta, espero que não se chateie.

Comment: Exato a resposta do hkotsubo é exatamente o que eu preciso

Comment: @HiagoSouza concordo plenamente com você, eu achei que seu problema era simples e acabei enganado e sem tempo, vou até remover minha sugestão de código. Inclusive editar a sua pergunta pra mais visibilidade.

Answer (score 3):

> Aparentemente o problema está no < no Edge não funciona, nem no Mozila. Qual o problema com a expressão?

O problema com a expressão é que ela utiliza o *negative lookbehind* (`?<!`).

Esse tipo *assertion* não é suportada por todos os browsers, só aqueles que utilizam o padrão **ECMA2018**.

Suas opções são:
 
Fazer a primeira varredura regex e após isso inverter o texto e utilizar novamente o *positive lookahead* já disponível na versão do **ECMA2015**, não recomendo fazer isso com grandes fluxos de dados, pois a performance será afetada ou 
esperar a atualização e não disponibilizar essa feature conforme identificação do browser utilizado.