# Regex com lookbehind não funciona no Firefox

Tags: javascript, regex

Criei um projeto em Angular e estou usando a seguinte expressão regular:

```
export const INTERFACE_REGEX = new RegExp(/(?<=.*\/)(.*?)(?=@|-.+)/gi);
```

Acontece que ao usar o Goggle Chrome o projeto funciona normal, mas se eu tentar abrir pelo Firefox dá erro:

> ```
> Erro: syntax invalid regex group
> ```

Eu fiz vários testes e descobri que se eu tirar o `?<=` da expressão deixa assim eu consigo compilar usando o firefox.

Qual seria o equivalente desse trecho da expressão `(?<=.*\/)`?

Answer (score 5):

> Nota: quando a pergunta foi feita, o Firefox não tinha suporte a *lookbehind* (por isso o erro), mas atualmente suporta e o erro não ocorre mais.

---

Primeiramente, um detalhe: não precisa construir a regex desta forma. Ao usar as barras (que é a [notação literal para expressões regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Literal_notation_and_constructor)), você já está criando um `RegExp`, então passá-lo para o construtor é redundante. Ou seja, as 4 formas abaixo são equivalentes:

```
regex = /expressão/gi;
regex = new RegExp('expressão', 'gi');
regex = new RegExp(/expressão/gi);
regex = new RegExp(/expressão/, 'gi');
```

Mas eu só usaria as 2 primeiras (a primeira se a expressão for "fixa", e a segunda se você tiver uma string que represente a expressão - [desde que se tome os devidos cuidados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/458289/112052)). As 2 últimas são redundantes (a última *talvez* seja útil em casos nos quais as [*flags*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags) são dinâmicas, mas vale lembrar que [ela só é válida a partir do ECMAScript 6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Flags_in_constructor)).

Dito isso, vamos ao problema em si:

---

O erro ocorre porque o trecho `(?<=.*\/)` é um [*lookbehind*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind), e na data em que esta resposta foi escrita, o Firefox não tinha suporte ([mas atualmente tem](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-RegExp_Lookbehind_Assertions), portanto não precisaria usar mais a solução abaixo, a menos que você precise dar suporte a algum dos *browsers* que ainda não suportam - por isso, de qualquer forma, fica documentada aqui a alternativa).

Enfim, existe uma forma de simular isso em qualquer outro ambiente que não suporte *lookbehind*. A ideia do *lookbehind* é verificar se algo existe antes do *match* atual. Sendo assim, basta quebrar a regex em duas (a parte que vem antes e o restante). Se eu encontrar um *match*, eu vejo se o que vem antes dele corresponde ao *lookbehind*. Mais ou menos assim:

```js
let r_match = /(.?)(?=@|-.+)/gi;
let lookbehind = /.*\/$/; // simula o lookbehind
let match;
let results = [];
while (match = r_match.exec('./a@ ./x-fd')) { // testando com uma string qualquer
  if (match.index == r_match.lastIndex) r_match.lastIndex++;
  // obtém a substring de zero até o índice em que o match ocorre
  let leftContext = match.input.substring(0, match.index);
  if (lookbehind.test(leftContext)) { // simular lookbehind
    results.push(match[1]);
  }
}
console.log(results); // [ 'a', 'x' ]
```

Então a ideia é primeiro verificar se tem um *match*. Depois eu pego a substring, do início da string até o ponto em que o *match* foi encontrado, e vejo se ele termina com o trecho correspondente ao *lookbehind*. Para isso adicionei o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$`, que significa o final da string. E nesse caso específico, a regex poderia ser apenas `/\/$/`- termina com `/` - pois `.*` significa "zero ou mais caracteres" e nesse caso não faz diferença ("terminar com zero ou mais caracteres seguidos de `/`" é a mesma coisa que "terminar com `/`").

Se quiser, você pode fazer `push` de todo o `match` (pois o objeto contém mais informações, como por exemplo o índice em que ocorre o *match*, etc). No caso, eu optei por apenas pegar o caractere correspondente a `(.?)`.

O `if (match.index == r_match.lastIndex)` é para corrigir um *bug* no caso de *zero width matches* ([explicado em detalhes aqui](http://www.regexguru.com/2008/04/watch-out-for-zero-length-matches/)).

---

Outra alternativa é não usar *lookbehind* e obter somente o grupo de captura correspondente à informação que você quer:

```js
let regex = /([^\/]*\/)(.?)(?=@|-.+)/gi;
let s = './a@ ./x-fd';
console.log([...s.matchAll(regex)].map(m => m[2])); // [ 'a', 'x' ]
```

Como agora o trecho `(.?)` é o segundo par de parênteses da expressão, ele está no grupo 2, por isso usei `m[2]` (mas você poderia eliminar o `map` caso queira um array com os *matches*).

E mudei o ponto para `[^\/]` (qualquer caractere que não seja `/`), pois senão a regex pode acabar pegando mais caracteres do que deve (inclusive a própria barra), dando resultados incorretos (como pegar somente o `x`, por exemplo).

Se bem que neste caso, não precisa do primeiro parênteses (assim, a informação que eu quero estará no grupo 1):

```js
let regex = /[^\/]*\/(.?)(?=@|-.+)/gi;
let s = './a@ ./x-fd';
console.log([...s.matchAll(regex)].map(m => m[1])); // [ 'a', 'x' ]
```

Por fim, a *flag* `i` serve para deixar a regex *case insensitive* (não diferencia letras maiúsculas e minúsculas). Mas como sua regex não tem letras, esta *flag* é desnecessária (pode deixar somente o `g`, que no seu caso não fará diferença).

---

Veja mais detalhes em ["Negative lookbehind só funciona no Google Chrome, existe uma alternativa para os outros browsers?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/361801/112052).

Answer (score -3):

Suporta a partir da versão 78, que foi lançada em junho de 2020.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#browser_compatibility