# Regex para encontrar um traço não seguido por letras

Tags: javascript, regex

Tenho a seguinte situação:

```js
const a = "          s - al";

console.log(a.match(/^-|(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])-/))
```

Essa regex atual retorna um match no "-", mas não deveria, pois existe uma letra precedida que é o "s".

Como faço pra pegar somente o primeiro traço que **não** é precedido por letras, como é este caso:

```
     - este traco
- este tambem
          - - somente o primeiro traco deve ser pego
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que vc quer... Vc quer dar match em "-" no início da sua string? Match no 1o "-"? Match somente quando a string iniciar por "-"? No seu 1o exemplo há espaços, já nos exemplos a seguir, não. Eles devem ser ignorados?

Answer (score 1):

A sua regex pega o hífen que está no início (`^-`), ou um hífen que não tem uma letra **imediatamente** antes. Como no seu código a string tem um espaço imediatamente antes do hífen, a regex encontra um *match*.

Neste caso você deveria considerar que podem ter espaços entre a letra e o hífen, por exemplo. Mas usando [*lookbehind*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) você fica um pouco limitado porque as *engines* de regex costumam ser restritivas quanto a esta construção (muitas não deixam colocar [quantificadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), que seria uma opção para os espaços opcionais, por exemplo), além de não funcionar bem em todos os browsers - veja mais sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/361801/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/459370/112052).

De qualquer forma, ficaria:

```
console.log(a.match(/^-|(?<![a-zA-Z0-9]\s*)-/));
```

Ou seja, depois das letras/números, tenho `\s*` (zero ou mais espaços). Lembrando que [*lookbehind* não é suportado em todos os browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-RegExp_Lookbehind_Assertions), e incluir quantificadores em um *lookbehind* também não é permitido em muitas *engines*.

Detalhe: se a string for `"s - - al"`, ela dará *match* no segundo hífen (que não ficou claro se deve ser encontrado ou não).

---

#### Sem usar *lookbehind*

Se a ideia for pegar o primeiro hífen que não tem nenhuma letra ou número em qualquer posição anterior, aí acho mais fácil fazer assim:

```js
const a = "         s - al";
let pos = a.indexOf('-');
if (pos < 0 || /[a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(a.slice(0, pos))) {
    console.log('não encontrou');
} else {
    console.log(`encontrou na posição ${pos}`);
}
```

Ou seja, primeiro eu procuro pelo hífen. Se encontrar, eu vejo se em qualquer posição anterior tem uma letra ou número (usando uma regex mais simples, sem *lookbehind*).

Pode parecer que ficou pior só porque "tem mais linhas", mas acho que fazer uma regex para isso, embora até acredito que seja possível, ficaria complicado demais para valer a pena. [Código menor não é necessariamente melhor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400495/112052).

Eu também retorno a posição do hífen porque me parece mais útil do que retornar o próprio hífen. Afinal, eu já sei que estou buscando por um hífen, então retornar este caractere é redundante - e no caso de ter mais de um hífen na string, como eu saberei qual deles deu *match*? Por isso acho que retornar a posição faz mais sentido nesse caso.

Se a ideia for ver se antes do hífen tem uma letra seguida de zero ou mais espaços, bastaria mudar a regex acima para `/[a-zA-Z0-9]\s*$/`(não ficou claro o critério, mas parece que pode ter apenas espaços entre a letra e o hífen).

---

E tem mais uma coisa que não ficou clara. Se a string for por exemplo `"x -   - al"`, o primeiro hífen está precedido por letra, mas e o segundo? Podemos considerar que sim (afinal, tem um "x" em uma posição anterior), ou não, pois só contamos depois do primeiro hífen?

Se for a primeira opção, o código acima já resolve. Mas se for a segunda opção, você teria que ir procurando por hífens até encontrar algum que satisfaça a condição (ou até não ter mais nenhum):

```js
const a = " x -  - al";
let pos = 0;
let posicaoEncontrada = -1;
while (pos < a.length) {
    let anterior = pos;
    // procura a partir da posição do último hífen encontrado
    pos = a.indexOf('-', pos);
    if (pos < 0)
        break;
    if (/[a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(a.slice(anterior, pos))) {
        pos++;
    } else {
        posicaoEncontrada = pos;
        break;
    }
}

// encontra o segundo hífen (posição 6)
if (posicaoEncontrada >= 0) {
    console.log(`encontrou na posição ${pos}`);
} else {
    console.log('não encontrou');
}
```